# Objective C Synchronous and asynchronous: Why is my protocol method called 6 times?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, synchronous

I am struggling with this, I try to summarize it with the most important pieces of code related to this issue.

I have a method which is responsible to query live times for a header in my app:

```
-(void)checkLiveTimesForHeader {
NSLog(@"Check Live times for header called");

if(self.crewTracker){
    if([MyInternetManager hasInternetConnection]){
        [self updateLoadingLabel];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            [self.crewTracker queryLivePosition];
        });
    } else {
        [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
            switch (status) {
                case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
                case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
                    [self checkLiveTimesForHeader];
                    break;
                default:
                    NSLog(@"Never called");
                    break;
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

}

The method queryLivePosition does multiple calculations and fires some synchronous calls on the internet. So I use synchronous calls since I was hoping the script "stops" there until it has a result. But I assume this is not the case? But I wouldn't know how to solve that, that is why I need your help...So my method queryLivePosition looks similar to this:

```
-(void)queryLivePosition
{
 ...do some stuff

     ... make some synchronous internet call
NSData *data =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:immutableRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
...

 //and then the protocol part:
if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(liveStatusQueried)]) [self.delegate liveStatusQueried];
}
```

The delegate method looks like this:

```
{
    NSLog(@"LiveStatus queried called");
    NSLog(@"LiveStatus Status: %lu", (unsigned long)self.crewTracker.liveStatus);
    NSLog(@"LiveStatus Results: %@", self.crewTracker.liveQueryResults);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.headerLayouter getLiveHeaderWithLiveQueryResults:self.crewTracker.liveQueryResults andLiveStatus:self.crewTracker.liveStatus];
    });
}
```

And my console output looks like this:

```
2019-05-15 15:52:08.508926+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.573481+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.634719+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.720259+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.791063+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.892758+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.939716+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus queried called
2019-05-15 15:52:08.939849+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
2019-05-15 15:52:08.939959+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940071+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940186+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940286+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940379+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940476+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940566+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940661+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
2019-05-15 15:52:08.940907+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
2019-05-15 15:52:08.941207+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
2019-05-15 15:52:08.941494+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
2019-05-15 15:52:08.941780+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Status: 1
:52:08.942015+0200 FollowMe[3055:137797] LiveStatus Results: (null)
```

So the output is completely messed up and not in order since first of all it should be only executed once (because my method checkLiveTimesForHeader is indeed only called once!) and all three nslog lines should be output after each other and not messy like this. So I assume it has to do that the internet response is too slow. But I already make the call synchronous...where is my error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it..sorry for the post. Wrote two setter methods which called themselves this queryLivePosition method. And these two setters were called by the log statements...